# Is there a way to listen to the paste event?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I can't find any document or window object that I can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event.

I know there is a clipboard variable but is there an event?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it would be possible to detect pastes with fairly high confidence by:

1. Subscribing to `workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`([workspace api)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace) to get all text edits
2. On edit, check `env.clipboard.readText()` to get the current content of the clipboard
3. From the `TextDocumentChangeEvent`, check each `contentChanges` entry's `text` and see if it matches the clipboard text
4. If it matches (and it isn't a trivial edit like a single character), they probably just pasted.